# When running Selenium tests on another machine, page element renders offscreen so tests fail

Tags: selenium

My test cases are successfully executing through the terminal and Maven in my local environment but when I run the tests in a Jenkins job, they fail due to the browser size. (I have taken a screenshot and from the screenshot I determined that browser size was small.)

(One thing I am not clear on is - Is the browser size dependent on the system screen size?)

My test tries to select a value from drop down but due to end of the page Selenium fails to select the value from drop down. The test passes locally, as the page is rendered so that the drop down is on screen and does not need to be scrolled to.

[image: Screenshot of running test showing parts of the page must be scrolled to reach them.]

If any one is aware about this issue please share your views and experience.

Comment: I don't understand the browser size thing. Test cases for Selenium should not fail due to size of browser, unless you are specifically adding that. Please attach the screenshot of the failure for better understanding.

Comment: The screenshot is of a browser from local machine or server?

Comment: @log_file:  it is from server

Comment: I see two drop down options. Which option are you selecting?

Comment: I am selecting from quantity dropdown

Comment: If you are maximizing your browser, and checking the element, it doesn't matter if the browser appears on screen or not.

Comment: What is the error that is thrown btw?

Comment: " Element is not attached to the document " and this is not happening every time

Comment: Your issue has absolutely nothing to do with Jenkins. It is all to do with the browser the tests are being run on being different.

Comment: @Eilidh I'm inclined to agree. However, it's possible this is something people will run into with Jenkins because of how clean the environment spawned to run them is. Depending on how the answers come across, I may remove the tag, but might keep it if it helps people find the answers they're looking for.

Comment: You should try using a headless browser, like HtmlUnit or PhantomJS.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the browser size in selenium is limited by the resolution of the display (Xvfb or similar on a build server).

So for example if your browser size is set as below, it can only fill the maximum of the display.

```
Dimension expectedWindowSize = new Dimension(1288, 988);
driver.manage().window().setSize(expectedWindowSize)
```

Basically it behaves the same as if you have a browser physically on your screen.  If you increase the build server's resolution, you will find it works.

This can be done using something similar to;

```
Xvfb :0 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
```

An easier solution is if you scroll down the page within Selenium to find the element you want before interacting with it.  You can do that with something like the below;

his will scroll until the element is in view :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id_of_dropdown"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
//click on dropdown and so on
```

Comment: Hello @Adurbe, Thanks for your valuable answer.Right now I am doing the 2nd approach (scrolling in to view the element).But calling scroll method every time before interacting the element is not such a good practice.So that I am looking for an alternative way.

Comment: As you said ,I will use Dimension class and update you the answer. Anyway Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: I have add how to set the Xvfb on the server, gives another option to follow.  Good luck!

Comment: Where should I place this "Xvfb :0 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24 &"

Comment: you would run it on the (linux) server your jenkins is running against
http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml

It basically sets the framebuffer on the system which is its "display size"

Comment: http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless

bit more info if it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the Info,But My jenkins is running on windows server

Comment: @QAMember Log on to your Windows server, open up the web application yourself in the browser - how does it display?

Comment: it looks same like my local browser